Error : Unsupported Server Component type: undefined in next js 14
i was learning new official next js 14 tutorial. to try : 
im on chapter 5 : 
and i was tried to add usePathname and clsx (just click the link see that) and after i add 'use client'; and i got this (see image)
where it uses is a sidebar and the sidebar in dashboard's layout
guys pls help answering or likeing
nav-links :
"use client";
import {
  UserGroupIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  DocumentDuplicateIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import clsx from "clsx";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

// Map of links to display in the side navigation.
// Depending on the size of the application, this would be stored in a database.
const links = [
  { name: "Home", href: "/dashboard", icon: HomeIcon },
  {
    name: "Invoices",
    href: "/dashboard/invoices",
    icon: DocumentDuplicateIcon,
  },
  { name: "Customers", href: "/dashboard/customers", icon: UserGroupIcon },
];

export default function NavLinks() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <>
      {links.map((link) => {
        const LinkIcon = link.icon;
        return (
          <Link
            key={link.name}
            href={link.href}
            className={clsx(
              `flex h-[48px] grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm font-medium hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3`,
              {
                "bg-sky-100 text-blue-600": pathname === link.href,
              }
            )}
          >
            <LinkIcon className="w-6" />
            <p className="hidden md:block">{link.name}</p>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}



i solved that just re comment component sidebar in layout.
my github acc
import SideNav from "@/app/ui/dashboard/sidenav";

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen flex-col md:flex-row md:overflow-hidden">
      <div className="w-full flex-none md:w-64">
        <SideNav />  
      </div>
      <div className="flex-grow p-6 md:overflow-y-auto md:p-12">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

firstly comment and save then remove the comment (//) and thats all

Just rebuild your application.
In terminal:
Ctrl + C, then
pnpm dev
